# Database Project, Assembly was not found in the SQL catalog

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclr, database-project

I have a SQL Server Database project in Visual Studio 2013. This project refer to another project called `BusinessLayer`.

BusinessLayer project has reference to System.Component.DataAnnotations and DataAnnotations is in .NET framework dll folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"

I also write a SQL CLR Trigger in DB Project, and when I deploy the database project, I got this error:
`SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6503, Level 16, State 12, Line 1`
`Assembly 'system.componentmodel.dataannotations, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35.' was not found in the SQL catalog.`

I tried to get the public key token of the dll and saw it is same as in the error. 
So what is this error and how to solve it?

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834070/upgrading-application-for-net-framework-4-5-cannot-get-correct-dataannotation)

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see it is answered...